# Dynamically change ToolTip of a Tool object

Tags: extjs4

Is there a way to change a tooltip text from a Tool placed in a panel? I looked at the ToolTip object and QuickTip but neither have a function like setTipText()

Thanks, Y_Y

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have two solutions for your problem!

1. Change HTML-attribute

   ```
   toolTip=Ext.ComponentQuery.query('tooltip[itemId=myToolTip]')[0];
   toolTip.html = "This is the new text!";
   toolTip.setTitle("new Title");
   toolTip.render();
   ```
2. Destroy the old one and make a new one...

   ```
   tooltip.destroy();
   var config = {
       target: 'bottomCallout',
       anchor: 'top',
       anchorOffset: 85, // center the anchor on the tooltip
       html: "Fancy new ToolTip with a totally different config..."
   };
   Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', config);
   ```

Comment: I tried the first solution and it seems like it's working. But for some reason I don't see the new text. It looks like I need to refresh the tool that has the tooltip somehow. Any ideas?

Comment: You are right, the first one worked not correctly... I have updated it! You have to call the render() method and the setTitle() method (if you have a title set in the first place).

Answer (score 5):

I wasn't able to put an itemId on my tooltip, so I was able to dynamically update the tooltip of a tool this way:

```
var toolTip = Ext.get(tool.getEl().id + '-toolEl');
toolTip.set({ 
    'data-qtitle': 'New Tooltip Title', //this line is optional
    'data-qtip': 'Updated Tool Tip!' 
});
```

Comment: You can use 'title': 'Updated Tool Tip!' if you want the other type of tooltip.